# SFTP Library for WinRT Windows 8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have been using Chilkat for SFTP in my existing application. The next project is a WinRT front end.

Is there a SFTP library for WinRT C#?

Comment: If you think the question has a problem, please comment the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts to find a SFTP library for WinRT, the answer must be no, but soon.

Search engines turned up no library and there is currently no other answer on StackOverflow.

Chilkat has promised a version in the future see: [sftp-c-library-for-winrt](http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/1681/sftp-c-library-for-winrt)

Comment: Hmm. SecureBlackbox had an SFTP client for WinRT since the beginning.